# Difference between `is_serialized_string` and `is_serialized`

Tags: codex

I have read the codex, but it is not quite clear to me: what's difference between [is_serialized](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_serialized) and [is_serialized_string](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_serialized_string) and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the source code of [`is_serialized()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L329) and [`is_serialized_string()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L396), the difference will become clear.

`is_serialized()` checks if the data is serialized, whereas `is_serialized_string()` checks, if the serialized data is of type string.

```
var_dump( is_serialized(        serialize(NULL) ) ); // true
var_dump( is_serialized_string( serialize(NULL) ) ); // false

var_dump( is_serialized(        serialize(array(1,2,3)) ) ); // true
var_dump( is_serialized_string( serialize(array(1,2,3)) ) ); // false

var_dump( is_serialized(        serialize("hello") ) ); // true
var_dump( is_serialized_string( serialize("hello") ) ); // true
```

([fiddle](https://3v4l.org/iqgnf))